# What medications (whether prescription or OTC) or home-remedies are used for stool-softeners or laxatives (to counteract constipation)?

Tags: gastroenterology, stools, constipation, otc-over-the-counter, laxative

Because I have been dealing with a lot of physical pain, I have been taking a lot of pain medication, which has the common side of effect of constipation. Obviously, this leads to painful defecation since they are hard to push through (sorry for the terrible image, but it's part of the body that we all deal with).

**What medications (whether prescription or OTC) or home-remedies are used for stool-softeners or laxatives (to counteract constipation)?**

Comment: The pharmacy sells an over the counter "stool softener".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a medical recommendation, you should speak to your doctor.

Generally speaking, paraffin oil, lactulose syrup and dietary fiber supplements are common OTC medications for constipation. It is important to drink plenty of water (specifically with added fiber). For individual advice, talk to your doctor.